# independence problem. Are they mutually independent? This is what i did

Tags: probability

We have an Ω={1,2,3,4}, and all of the elemental events have the same probability.

Then we have A={1,2}, B={1,3} and C={1,4}.

Are A, B, C mutually independent?

I tried to show that P(A∩B∩C)=P(A)P(B)P(C).

And we have that P(1)=1/4, also P(A∩B∩C)= P(1)=1/4. And P(A)=(1/4*1/4)=P(B)=P(C).

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What is $P(A)$ again?  There are two outcomes out of four equally likely outcomes that make up $A$.  Was $P(A)=\frac{1}{4}\cdot \frac{1}{4}$?  Or was $P(A)$ something to do with the number of favorable outcomes over the total number of outcomes?

Comment: The events do not satisfy the definition of mutual independence, they are 2-wise but not 3-wise independent.

Comment: For your conclusion, is $P(A\cap B\cap C)$ actually equal to $P(A)P(B)P(C)$?  If they are equal what does that mean?  If they are not equal, what does *that* mean?

Comment: @JMoravitz I think that P(A) is the event that happens (1,2).

Comment: JMoravitz If P(A∩B∩C)=P(A)P(B)P(C) then they are independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $\mathsf P(A) = \tfrac 1 2 = \mathsf P(\{1\})+\mathsf P(\{2\})$, etc.

Then $\mathsf P(A)~\mathsf P(B)~\mathsf P(C) = (\tfrac 12)^3 = \tfrac 1 8$

And since  $\mathsf P(A\cap B \cap C) = \mathsf P(\{1\}) = \tfrac 1 4$, we conclude...

---

However $\mathsf P(A\cap B) = \mathsf P(A\cap C)=\mathsf P(B\cap C)= \mathsf P(\{1\}) = \tfrac 14 $

And since $\mathsf P(A)\mathsf P(B) = (\tfrac 12)^2 = \tfrac 14$, et cetera, then we conclude....

Comment: Then they are not independent right? Also can you explain me why  $\mathsf P(A) = \tfrac 1 2 = \mathsf P(\{1\})+\mathsf P(\{2\})$ is because your doing P(1,2)=P(1)+P(2)-P(1U2)=P(1)+P(2) because P(1∩2)=0?

Comment: @neto333 An axiom of probability is that $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)$ whenever $A\cap B=\emptyset$.  Notice that $A=\{1\}\cup \{2\}$ and further notice that $\{1\}$ and $\{2\}$ are mutually exclusive.

Comment: @neto333 Yes, $\mathsf P(A) = \mathsf P(\{1\}\cup\{2\})$.

Comment: One more thing, then we can conclude that they are mutually independent? Then why we cant conclude that P(A∩B∩C)=P(A)P(B)P(C)

Comment: @neto333 we concluded that $P(A\cap B\cap C)$ is **not equal** to $P(A)P(B)P(C)$, which implies that they are **not mutually independent**.

Comment: @neto333 It is permissible to be *pairwise independent* but *not mutually independent*; indeed it *quite often* happens to be the case.  (It is *why* there are the two phrases).  This exercise is meant to be a demonstration of that fact.